# Android Studio Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: android, gradle

I Open a existing project to android studio
and get this

[image]

> Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32
>        application

Comment: Can you show your root level and app level build.gradle? And what version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: I use the latest gradle version .

Comment: I use this https://github.com/The-LoneWolf/AndroPress

Comment: I was able to checkout and open this project in AS 2.2.2.

Comment: i use windows xp and android Studio   AS 2.2.2 ,so what must i do now?

Comment: If you're using 32-bit Windows XP, you'll also need to use 32-bit Java and 32-bit everything. I didn't know Android Studio still published a 32-bit version.

Answer (score 3):

You should check the JDK Location settings, which appears be changed on every Android Studio update, with commands ctrl + Alt + Shift + S (to reveal the Project Structure menu options, and uncheck the Use embedded JDK and find your current JDK Location, on windows machines, you can see that location on environment variables JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.
You probably need to download a full release of Android Studio (see Note).
They are .zip files form here:
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

E.G. If you Android Studio (Windows) is in "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio":

1. Rename "Android Studio" to "Android Studio.old"
2. Unzip the release to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio".

> ```
> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\
>                                         +---bin
>                                         |
>                                         +---gradle
>                                         |
>                                         +---jre
>                                         |
>                                         +---lib
>                                         |
>                                         +---license
>                                         |
>                                         +---plugins
> ```

Note: Android Studio 2.3 Canary 1 had **issues** in it's patching system,
so a full download is needed when moving from Canary 1 to Canary 3.
Android Studio 2.2.X should offer patches from major stable releases.
All other users will need to **download a full release** to update.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the last android studio from here https://developer.android.com/studio
and it will hopeful work

Answer (score 0):

Download platform-tools for windows from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r31.0.2-windows.zip and unpack it in ~Android/Sdk. This will replace the platform-tools folder.